# Parser: The end of the input was reached

Tags: ssrs-2008, mdx

I'm very new to MDX and don't know what this error "Parser:  The end of the input was reached" means.

I ran my code in mdx and it is pulling correct data.  However, when I take my code and put it into my SSRS report, I get the above error.  What am I be doing wrong?

Here's my MDX:

```
SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Cash Expend] } ON COLUMNS, NON EMPTY 
     { ( [Documents].[Doc No].[Doc No].ALLMEMBERS * 
  [Vendor].[Vendor Name].[Vendor Name].ALLMEMBERS * 
  [Documents].[Accept Date].[Accept Date].ALLMEMBERS ) } 
  DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS 
FROM ( SELECT ( { [Account Type].[AT].&[22] } ) ON COLUMNS 
FROM ( SELECT ( { [Documents].[BFY].&[2008]
                , [Documents].[BFY].&[2009]
                , [Documents].[BFY].&[2010]
                , [Documents].[BFY].&[2011] } ) ON COLUMNS 
 FROM ( SELECT ( { [Transaction Code].[TC].&[PV] } ) ON COLUMNS 
  FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOMEMBER(@FromDocumentsAcceptDate) : STRTOMEMBER(@ToDocumentsAcceptDate) ) ON COLUMNS 
   FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET(@VendorVendCode) ) ON COLUMNS 
    FROM [FMCS])))) 
WHERE ( [Transaction Code].[TC].&[PV],
  [Account Type].[AT].&[22],   
 IIF( STRTOSET(@VendorVendCode).Count = 1, STRTOSET(@VendorVendCode), [Vendor].[Vend Code].currentmember ) ) 
CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your first paren in this line:

```
FROM ( SELECT ( { [Account Type].[AT].&[22] } ) ON COLUMNS 
     ^this one
```

is not being closed.  My first thought is that it should be closed just before your `WHERE` clause but i'm not sure.